# Django makemessages not creating newly added languages

Tags: python, django, translation, django-i18n, makemessages

I had 12 languages in my Django app, if I run the command:

```
python manage.py makemessages --all
```

It would create all the 12 .po files for the languages, now I added 3 more languages:

```py
LANGUAGES = (
    ...
    ('th', gettext('Thai')),
    ('tl', gettext('Tagalog')),
    ('vi', gettext('Vietnamese')),
)
```

When I run the `makemessages --all` command, it just skips the three new languages. Am I missing something?

Edit: Maybe the documentation is hard to understand:

> **makemessages**
>
> django-admin makemessages
>
> Runs over the entire source tree of the current directory and pulls
> out all strings marked for translation. It creates (or updates) a
> message file in the conf/locale (in the Django tree) or locale (for
> project and application) directory. After making changes to the
> messages files you need to compile them with compilemessages for use
> with the builtin gettext support. See the i18n documentation for
> details.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to specify the languages you are interested in the first time at the command line.

```
python manage.py makemessages -l th -l tl -l vi
```

After that, subsequent calls with `--all` flag will generate PO files for all languages.

Comment: In case it helps someone, I had the opposite problem...  I removed an entry from LANGUAGES but I think it generates that language if it discovers any files with that language code.  You can use `-x` to not generate/update a particular language.

Answer (score 0):

You should run [the command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemessages-locale) below. *The command below can create or update one or more `django.po`:

```
django-admin makemessages --locale=th --locale=tl --locale=vi
```

Or:

```
django-admin makemessages -l th -l tl -l vi
```

Actually, [the command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemessages-all) below can only update all `django.po` but cannot create `django.po`:

```
django-admin makemessages --all
```

Or:

```
django-admin makemessages -a
```